# Jenkins SVN Tag Parameter from CLI

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I recently attempted to use Jenkins-CLI with an SVN tag parameter. I received this error message.

> `CLI parameter submission is not supported for the class hudson.scm.listtagsparameter.ListSubversionTagsParameterDefinition type. Please file a bug report for this.`

My command

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s [JENKINS_URL] build [BUILD] -s -p VERSION=trunk
```

Does anyone know a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs when plugin (in this case the subversion-plugin) does not support CLI parameter submission.

And really, if you take a look in the [source code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/subversion-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/scm/listtagsparameter/ListSubversionTagsParameterDefinition.java) of the class specified in error, there is only support for parameter submission from GET and POST HTTP requests, and from "Build" button in Jenkins GUI.

The best thing to do would be to submit a bug report for this issue.

You can see similar bug report for another plugin [here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22924)